# Posso usar compressão GZIP em arquivos que foram minificados pelo Gulp ou Grunt?

Tags: linux, grunt, gulp, gulpjs, gzip

Posso usar compressão GZIP em arquivos que foram minificados pelo Gulp ou Grunt? Gostaria de saber se há possibilidade de eu ter problemas em relação a isso. Ou se eu teria um carregamento ainda mais rápido do lado do browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é uma boa ideia minificar seus arquivos `.js` e `.css` e depois disso comprimi-los utilizando `gzip`.

Eu fiz um simples teste com o [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/). Baixei o jQuery não-minificado **e** o minificado:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 258648 Mar 17 23:32 jquery-2.2.2.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group  85656 Mar 17 23:32 jquery-2.2.2.min.js
```

Perceba que o jQuery não-minificado possui `258 Kb` e o minificado `85 Kb`.

E depois disso eu comprimi os dois arquivos utilizando o comando `gzip -9` (`-9` representa a compressão mais lenta e mais efetiva):

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group  76515 Mar 17 23:32 jquery-2.2.2.js.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group  29763 Mar 17 23:32 jquery-2.2.2.min.js.gz
```

O arquivo jQuery apenas *comprimido* possui `76 Kb`, enquanto o jQuery *minificado **e** comprimido* possui `29 Kb`.

E já que você já está utilizando o `Grunt`, dê uma olhada no [`grunt-contrib-compress`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compress) para automatizar a compressão dos arquivos.

Comment: Muito bom seu teste cara, super esclarecedor, obrigado!